# Delphi datasnap REST server - Auto login for Android and ios client applications

Tags: rest, delphi, token, firemonkey, datasnap

I have created a Delphi Datasnap REST server that provides api end points to android and ios client applications.

On `UserAuthenticate` method, I set the valid flag to true so that subsequent calls to any api endpoint doesn't require any authentication.

When I login through android/ios application for the first time, next time when a user opens the application I want him to automatically login(auto -login kind of feature).

I did some diggings but could not find much help on how to implement access token. Please suggest your thoughts on the following queries:

1. How do I generate an access token based on the User device ID ?
2. Which is the location to store such token info on android and ios ?
3. How to use this token for validating the authentication during subsequent api calls ?

or Is there any easier or in-built feature to save the user authentication on client side ?

Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like you're going to have to write some code.

Comment: I implemented it by generating a token at client-side, keeping one local copy in sync with the server.